# Read cookies from ADFS Single Sign On

Tags: asp.net, cookies, single-sign-on, adfs

Good morning,

On my test-site I implemented SSO (SAML2.0 from ComponentSpace) which works great, but the next level - live situation- is giving me a headache…

My customer is using ADFS for authentication and when a user accesses my site (in the cloud) for the first time, my site generates a nice SAML-request which is answered with a SAML-response from ADFS. The user is logged-in. All well so far.

But, when the users accesses my site for the second time ADFS does not response anymore to my SAML-request. After digging into this situation it seems that ADFS saves the first time several cookies on the client webbrowser (under its own domain-name) and when ADFS detects those 4 cookies the second time it does not respond to my SAML-request.

I searched several sites and found a good document about this behaviour on https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/en%C2%ADus/library/bb897402. The solution in this article is based on AzMan, but we use the latest Windows server 2012R2 which AzMan is deprecated.

So how do I deal with this situation?

1. How can I detect and read from my domain the cookies from the adfs.customerdomainname.nl?
2. The cookies are encrypted. How can I decrypt them, to get the right UserId from it?
3. Is there a good sample on how to implement SSO in combination with ADFS?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

best regards,
Arno

Comment: It's hard to believe that ADFS IdP does not send a SAML assertion when  the user already has a session with the IdP. That would make it impossible to integrate multiple SPs (Apps) with ADFS based IdP.

Are you sure you are properly performing SAMLv2 SP-initiated SSO? 
You can read the cookie of anonther domain as the browser is not allowed to send the cookie to your site for security reasons, see 'cookie spec' https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265

Comment: Yes, adfs idp does not send a response to the SAML2.0 request once it detects its own (4) cookies. The cookies are stored on its own domain-name adf.<customerdomain>.nl and my domain is differents of cources. I tried several options to read the cookies, but with no success.
Any suggestion how I can access the ADFS-cookies. They contain the claims which I need.

Comment: You shouldn't have to decrypt the cookies to read the claims, just the SAML assertion (via the "input['SAMLResponse']" field as sent via the POST request. Then you decrypt it using a properly configured SecurityTokenHandlerCollection, which would need to be setup using the private key certificate that you need to decrypt. The SecurityTokenHandlerCollection type has a ReadToken method that will return an actual Saml2SecurityToken object. You can then call ValidateToken (another method on SecurityTokenHandlerCollection) to validate the token and receive a list of ClaimsIdentities.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this article from IBM: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYJ99_8.5.0/dev-portlet/add_cookie_adfs.html. It essentially says you would need to configure ADFS to create cookies such that they have the same domain as your website.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We stopped temporarily with this implementation because it gave us a huge headache.  We plan to restart the SSO in January-2018. I will absolutely test this one and report back the results.

Answer (score 1):

I'd similar issue while authenticating users with ADFS 3.0 from a C# MVC web application. The reason was that while cookies are still active (not-expired) they cannot be overwritten so to fix this issue I created a new CookieManager instead of using the default one. Below is the line of code that worked for me.

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
        });
```